# Mejor forma de saber si no tiene datos un atributo tipo boolean | string Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo una clase que tiene definidos varios campos como el siguiente:

```js
expectativa: string | boolean;
```

En el backend en Java tengo unas comprobaciones para ver si es vacío del siguiente modo:

```java
((expectativa == null) || !expectativa.equals("1")) &&
```

porque en el back es sólo un String.

Ahora necesito hacer esa comprobación en el front, en Typescript (Angular).

¿Cómo sería la mejor forma de hacerlo?
Debe considerar que no tiene datos en los siguientes casos:

- si es nulo,
- si es string y es cadena vacía
- si es string y no es '1'
- si es booleano y es false

Comment: Si necesitas verificar el tipo de variable puedes probar el operador typeof o cuál es el problema?

Comment: En typescript se pueden hacer muchas cosas de una vez usando características propias del lenguaje. Yo podría empezar a hacer cada una de las comprobaciones pero a veces el lenguaje te ofrece esas características y puede que no la use porque no lo conozco. Por ejemplo, cuando se usa === o de ?.

Comment: En la solución que he puesto después he utilizado el typeof. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar la lógica y posteriormente negarlo.

```js
// para el caso indicado de string|boolean
tieneDato = tieneDato || (obj.expectativa && (obj.expectativa === true || obj.expectativaEso === '1'));

// para el caso de una string
tieneDato = tieneDato || (obj.otrosIntereses!= null && typeof obj.otrosIntereses !== "undefined" && obj.otrosIntereses.length > 0 );
...
return !tieneDato;
```

Aún así, me gustaría dar con una solución mejor si existiera.

Comment: Quizá te interese [ver](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard)